# Inserting from a huge table ( 1.8 billion records ) taking a lot of time in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am a beginner in snowflake and am trying benchmark a few queries with very high volume in snowflake. Currently my use-case is to insert a huge volume in a table.

The syntax is :

```
Insert into tab1 ( cola,colb,colc ... colx) 
    Select ( cola,colb,colc ... colx) 
    from tab2;
```

The 1.8 billion row insert is taking around 16 minutes. Is there anything that I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Is the source a table or a view? What size of virtual warehouse are you using? Are you inserting into empty table or appending?

Comment: Source is a table. Size of the warehouse is medium . I am inserting into an empty table. @LukaszSzozda

Comment: that's 1.6m records/second.  Not terrible

Comment: @user3451371 Is the target table clustered? Second: have you tried scaling warehouse up to large?

Comment: the target table is auto clustered, i tried explicit clustering with key fields but it did not help.  Scaling warehouse to large is not an option since we have to use the medium warehouse only. That is a sort of restriction you might say. @LukaszSzozda

Comment: Hi , are you inserting from Snowflake to Snowflake or is it any other database ? If it is only Snowflake to Snowflake and then why don't you do a CTAS , Create Table as SELECT * from Source.

Comment: Why do you think anything is wrong? What performance are you expecting to see and what is that expectation based on?

Comment: This query in teradata takes around a minute to execute. I am trying to benchmark it against that performance. I understand that the benchmark might not be apple to apple , but a jump from 1 min to 16 mins is a considerable jump. hence I thought there might be something that I am missing while data modelling or anywhere else. @NickW

Comment: Please post the query profile.  Besides the row count, what's the footprint of this data set in TBs?

Comment: If you are doing a straight insert into an empty target table then the only thing you can tune in Snowflake is the warehouse size - though, as another commentator has mentioned, there are potentially more performant ways to achieve what you want i.e. with CTAS or cloning. Also without knowing your Teradata specification its impossible to make a comparison: you might be running on the world’s most over-specified Teradata environment so comparison to a Medium sized Snowflake warehouse (which is at the low-end of available sizes) is meaningless

Comment: @JimDemitriou . The data is around 1.2 TB.

Comment: Just to make sure, you're inserting data into a table that already has data, or is this a table copy?

Answer (score 1):

This is a resource-bounded operation. You are not sharing how many resources your Teradata instance has, so we can't give you a meaningful comparison.

In any case, I tried benchmarking how long it takes to insert 6 billion rows:

```sql
create or replace table letstrythis 
as 
select *
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1000.lineitem
limit 0
;

insert into letstrythis
select *
from snowflake_sample_data.tpch_sf1000.lineitem
-- 6B rows 
-- 13m37s M
-- 1m26s 3XL
```

You can see a huge difference between the M and the 3XL virtual warehouses: 13 minutes vs 1 minute to load these 6 billion rows.